# How can I post to a databse in Classic ASP using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, asp-classic

I have a sortable list that allows me to rearrange the items by dragging and dropping them. When I rearrange the items, the number inside the input tags adjust according to their new position within the list. AT this point what I'd like to do is post the new input value(s) to a field within my database.

Below is the Classic ASP code

```
<form name="sort_award" action="file_2.asp?Action=sort" method="post">
<%
end if
response.write "<ul id='sortable'>"
dim i
i=1

While not rsAwards.EOF

response.write "<li onclick='sort("&rsAwards("Award_ID")&")'> &nbsp 
<input type='text' name='AwardNumber' size='1' value="&i&"> &nbsp 
<label name='AwardName'>" & rsAwards("Award_Name") & "</label>"
%>
<a href='edit_awards.asp?Action=edit&Award_ID=<%=rsAwards("Award_ID")%>' name='AwardID'>Edit</a>&nbsp;
<a class="lb" href='file_1.asp?Action=delete&Award_ID=<%=rsAwards("Award_ID")%>'>Delete</a></li>
<%
rsAwards.MoveNext
i=i+1
Wend

%></ul>
<input type="submit" value="Sort">
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({ placeholder: "ui-state-highlight" });
});

function sort(AwardID) {
  var count = document.getElementById('sortable').getElementsByTagName('li').length;
  var AwardNum = document.getElementById('sortable').getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      AwardNum[i].setAttribute('value', i+1);     
    }
 }
```

Comment: You would use $.ajax or $.post to have jquery send the data to a .asp script pon your server.

Comment: JavaScript can't access your database (at least, I *really* hope it can't... otherwise you have bigger problems).  You're going to need to use AJAX to send data to a server-side resource (likely another "page" in this setup) which accepts the data (query string values, form post values, whichever you'd prefer) and performs the server-side logic against the database.  There's a hard separation of a service layer between the client-side code and the server-side code.  What you need to do is create your endpoints for that service layer.

Comment: file_2 processes the form data and posts it to the database. I'm new to Jquery and not quite familiar with ajax. how would i use $.post?

Comment: Here's an article on how to do this in Classic ASP using AJAX: http://halnesbitt.com/blog/2010/08/05/save-order-with-jquery-ui-sortable-and-aspaccess/

Comment: I tried this and it wouldn't post to my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

You can easily post data through ajax to your asp page by using [`.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

If you are doing a get request, then you can use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) instead, it is much less complicated.

(NOTE: jQuery includes a bunch of other ajax request functions as well, like `.ajax()`, `.load()`, etc. but I find `.get()` to be my go to function for this because it allows more flexibility and usage functions are needed to remember)

To use it, simply do this:

```
<script>
$.get("myasppage.asp?id=12345", function(data){

   //after the request is complete, you can place any code here that you want
   //therefore, your code won't continue processing until the request is done.

   //if the .asp page returns content like "HELLO!", then that would be in your
   // data variable, as defined up top.  So you can just do this.


   $(body).append(data); //<- appends the data from myasppage.asp to your body content

   alert(data); // <- will popup an alert box with the content returned from your asp page



});
</script>
```

That's it. :)

Comment: this just updates the values on my form, I've already done that. What I'm trying to do is post that data to my database. How could I use .post() instead?

Comment: @n3tak0 to make it work you need to have page called "myasppage.asp" that will check `Request.QueryString("id")` and when not blank, add to database. That's the essence of AJAX, which you seem to have missed.

Comment: Instead of requiring post, why don't you just change `Request.Form("field1")` in your asp page to `Request("field1")` instead?  This allows you to accept either form or querystring in your request.  Otherwise, you can find an example of posting a form in jquery here (same url provided in my answer): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/